# Netapp SMVI and SMSQL Backup strategies

Tags: snapshot, netapp

Netapp VMWare Sql Server VM's using SMVI to backup OS and SMSQL to backup DB's Windows and generic data drive on one volume, SQL MDF's on another, SQL TempDB on another and SQL Logs and SMSQL SI on a fourth.  My DataCenter Storage Engineers tell me that when they snap the OS using SMVI since all of those volumes are in attached to the VM, all of them are included in the snap.  Is there a way to exclude at least the TempDB from the snap, if not all of the SQL related volumes?  I am concerned with Snap Reserve space as we had our main production SQL server go down because the Snap Reserve filled and TempDB was left with not enough space to complete our nightly batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was a version issue.  The SMVI was updated to a newer version and now the volumes that SMSQL will be responsible for can be removed from the SMVI snapshots.